# What is the maximum statement length in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm building a SQL statement that contains data and I'm wondering if I would break some maximum statement length in Oracle 10g.

The statement would be about 3 200 000 bytes, cannot be split and has to be parsable in its entirety.

Before I'm investing too much time this way, I was wondering if I would be limited by the size of this statement.

I am using SQL developer but I think that if the server can do it, so can SQL developer.

Comment: What you mean by "request"? I've ran a script of 20.1MB (which contains inserts.) If the code were embraced in BEGIN/END keywords then SQLDeveloper hanged. If the commands were script-like, it runs smoothly.

Comment: @FlorinGhita I mean only one statement. It would be a MERGE ... USING, with the USING clause being composed of lots of SELECTs that would be UNIONed.

Comment: Worst case, just create a view ;)

Comment: You're begging the question. Don't put your data in the SQL statement - e.g. put it in a table, or bind it in.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no fixed number. See "Logical Database Limits":  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits003.htm

"The limit on how long a SQL statement can be depends on many factors, including database configuration, disk space, and memory".

You might also be affected by other limits, such as the maximum levels of subqueries.

Given that the maximum length of PL/SQL procedures is given as 2000-3000 lines, my feeling is that you may run into problems with a 3M bytes query. I also think that if it works at all, the parse time will be "interesting".

Comment: Hi, Chris! Do you have any practical experience on how to estimate the max size? This phrase from the docs is really frustrating.

Comment: I've never had the necessity to use such long statements, so no, I don't have any practical experience with it.

Comment: I see, thank you. Just accidentally overcame this situation, 226K length query (with a lot of autogenerated `IN (...)` clauses) causing an error, while the reduced to 100K query with the same structure finishes normally.

Comment: @AlexeyTrofimov maybe you hit the 1000 elements in IN clause upper limit?

Answer (score -1):

According 11.2 Limits documentation:

> Maximum length of SQL statement, including the NULL terminator.   409,600

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21643/limit.htm#TTREF455

Comment: Your link points to "TimesTen In-Memory Database Reference", so I think it is quite misleading considering the question is more about Oracle's SQL server.